# How to find eigenvalues & eigenvectors of this 3 by 3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -3 &-4 \\ 0 & 3 & 0\\ 2 & 1 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$

I found eigenvalues $1$ and $3$ with multiplicity of $2$. How do I find the eigenvectors now?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about typesetting your question so it is easier to read.

Comment: the minimal polynomial is the same as the characteristic polynomial. This means you look for a column vector $w$ such that $(A-3I)^2 w = 0$  but $(A-3I) w \neq 0.$ Then two columns in the transformation matrix $P$ are $v = (A-3I)w$ and $w.$ The left column is the eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$

Comment: To find eigenvectors in general just solve the system $AX=\lambda X$ for $X=(x,y,z)^T$. You will often have more variables than equations, so you can set some freely let say $x=1$ for instance. Your eigenvalues are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your eigenvalues, $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=3$.

As you already have these I'll not put my working for them.

The standard theory is that we now solve,
$$\begin{bmatrix}-1-\lambda & -3 &-4 \\0 & 3-\lambda & 0\\2 &1 &5-\lambda\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}X \\Y \\Z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

For $\lambda=1$ and let X=1,
$$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -3 &-4 \\0 & 2 & 0\\2 &1 &4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\Y \\Z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Middle Row yields $2Y=0$ so $Y=0$

Bottom Row yields $2+Y+4Z=0$ so $Z=-\frac{1}{2}$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
which is more conveniently expressed as
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 \\0 \\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

For $\lambda=3$,
$$\begin{bmatrix}-4 & -3 &-4 \\0 & 0 & 0\\2 &1 &2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\Y \\Z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Top Row yields $-4-3Y-4Z=0$

Bottom Row yields $2+Y+2Z=0$

Solve these simultaneously to get $Y=0$ and $Z=-1$

Thus the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=3$ is,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

When we get three real eigenvalues with repetitions it corresponds to one of several types of 3D shear

There is a good tutorial with examples of what can happen with various multiplicities of eigenvectors and what the implications are here : Link https://sites.calvin.edu/scofield/courses/m256/materials/eigenstuff.pdf

Hope this answers your question : it's a while since I did one of these so I enjoyed revising the process.

Comment: My confusion comes from the issues that 3 is a multiplicity of 2 which means that it should have 2 answers not just (1,0,-1). I need the second values on order to find the general solution don't I ?

Comment: An eigenvalue with multiplicity greater than $1$ need not have more than one eigenvector up to scaling. Consider $(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})$. Its characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^2$ but its only eigenvector up to scaling is $\binom{1}{0}$.

Comment: @OP We call these eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicity (here $2$) different from geometric multiplicity (here $1$) : defective eigenvalues. This simply means that the initial matrix is not diagonalisable, but only trigonalisable. One canonical form for the triangular matrix obtained is called the Jordan form. You can search for these terms for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The other vector that you're missing is the solution of
$$
     (A-3I)X = \left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{array}\right]
$$
This vector $X$ satisfies $(A-3I)^2X=0$. This vector, along with the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $3$ and $1$ will give you want you want.